# view one has_many record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git

```
  Restaurant Load (1.5ms)  SELECT * FROM "restaurants" INNER JOIN "restaurant_branches" ON "restaurant_branches"."restaurant_id" = "restaurants"."restaurant_id"
+----------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| resta... | res_... | res_... | crea... | updat... | user_id | resta... | addr... | addr... | addr... | addr... | addr... | addr... | numb... | numb... | email |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
| 27       | DOGG... | WE S... | 2014... | 2014-... | 4       | 28       | 405 ... |         | CHICAGO | IL      | 60666   | USA     |         |         |       |
| 27       | DOGG... | WE S... | 2014... | 2014-... | 4       | 29       | 111 ... |         | CHICAGO | IL      | 60661   | USA     |         |         |       |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+
```

As you can see I have a model restaurants and restaurant_branches. How would I approach if I want to open a restaurant record and ONLY ONE branch? Because right now, my form displays all the branches. How will I open this on my index.html.erb file so that my show.html.erb file will only be one restaurant_branches? Thank you for any help.

```
<h1>
  <strong>Restaurant Name:</strong>
  <%= @restaurant.res_name %>
</h1>

<p>
  <strong>Restaurant Description:</strong>
  <%= @restaurant.res_description %>
</p>
<ol class="restaurant_branch_fields">
    <% @restaurant.restaurant_branches.each do |f| %>
      <li>
        <p><strong>Address</strong><%= f.set_address %></p>
        <p><strong>Contact Info</strong><%= f.set_contact_info  %></p>
      </li>
     <% end %>
</ol>

<p>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_restaurant_path(@restaurant) %>
<%= link_to "Destroy", @restaurant, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
<%= link_to "View All", restaurants_path %>
</p>

class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @restaurant = Restaurant.get_list
  end

  def show
    #@restaurant = Restaurant.select('*').joins(:restaurant_branches).find_by(:restaurant_id => params[:id], :restaurant_branches => {:restaurant_branch_id => params[:id]})
    #@restaurant = Restaurant.joins(:restaurant_branches).find_by(:restaurant_id => params[:id], :restaurant_branches => {:restaurant_branch_id => params[:restaurant_branch_id]})
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new
  end

  def create
    if user_signed_in?
      @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)
      if @restaurant.save
        redirect_to @restaurant
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      redirect_to new_owner_session_path
    end
  end

  def edit
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
    if @restaurant.update_attributes(restaurant_params)
      flash.now[:notice] = "You have successfully updated #{@restaurant.res_name.titleize}."
      redirect_to @restaurant
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
    @restaurant.destroy
    flash.now[:notice] = "#{@restaurant.res_name.titleize} has been deleted!"
    redirect_to restaurants_url
  end

  private

  def restaurant_params
    params.require(:restaurant).permit(:res_name, :res_description, restaurant_branches_attributes: [ :id, :address_line1, :address_line2, :address_line3, :address_line4, :address_line5, :address_line6, :number_phone, :number_fax, :email, :_destroy, pictures_attributes: [ :id, :name, :image, :_destroy] ] ).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}
  resources :restaurants do
        resources :restaurant_branches, shallow: true
  end

  root to: 'restaurants#index'
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would add a `RestaurantBranchesController` and load the branch by its `id`.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am a newbie in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page displays all the branches because of this iteration:

```
<% @restaurant.restaurant_branches.each do |f| %>
```

`@restaurant.restaurant_branches` contains all the branches, and `.each` will loop through them.

If you need to access only the **first** of those branches you can use this code in your controller's view action

```
@branch = @restaurant.restaurant_branches.first
```

Then in your view:

```
<p><strong>Address</strong><%= @branch.address %></p>
<p><strong>Contact Info</strong><%= @branch.contact_info  %></p>
```

If you need the last branch you could have use in your controller `@branch = @restaurant.restaurant_branches.last`

If you need a specific id of a branch you could have use in your controller `@branch = @restaurant.restaurant_branches.find(123)`

Comment: Thing is, the selection for the record comes from a table that displays those two rows. So using first and last won't do. I need to find a way to query not just the primary key for the restaurants but also the primary key of restaurant_branches. Any ideas?

Comment: But how do I get the value from the joined models to set the criteria for find?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that, I'm not even sure to understand the question :)

Comment: Basically, I am trying to build a page where a restaurant can only have one branch.

Comment: In this case you should have a `has_one` not a `has_many` relationship, and all your design must change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you really want that each restaurant can have only one branch then I suggest you go with `has_one` relationship instead of `has_many`.

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :restaurant_branch
end

class RestaurantBranch < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

Of course, you have to update your controller and views a bit as you will reference the restaurant_branch like this

```
@restaurant.restaurant_branch #without 'es'
```

More information: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

Regards